# Is it possible to unmute a muted microphone on Windows 11?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-addon-api

I'm facing a challenge with my recording application on clients using Windows 11. Some of these clients have their microphone already muted at the operating system level, which prevents my application from functioning properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcSO0.png)

My application is developed on Electron/React/Webpack

Investigating the use of Node.js addons to interact with the system's audio settings programmatically.